# Can I modify a Google Document document table from Android or on the Web?

Tags: google, google-drive, documents

I have an Android 4.4.2 KitKat device with the Google Drive and Google Docs apps installed. With these I am able to open a Google Drive document but I would then like to insert a row or a column in a table, and cannot find the functionality to do this from within the Drive or Docs apps.

- Is it possible to insert table rows or columns from Drive or Docs apps?
- Otherwise, do I need to download the file first, and if so, then what app should I use to do the modification?
- Or should I use the Chrome web browser on my device to insert the table rows or columns, and how is this operation carried out?
- Or should I just give these three options up, download to my PC, open with MS Word or LibreOffice, then upload back (at the cost of having to sit at my PC's table to do this)?

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

What OS are you running @LieRyan? I don't have the ellipsis which appears in your menu. I ended up using an application called OfficeSuite, which despite being a bit pricy at about 15$ a year, can edit Google Docs apps and manipulate tables contained therein without having to download the document to the device and then upload it again.

OK, here is the screenshot from Google Drive on my device. As you can see the ellipses allowing the table to be edited are missing:

[image]

Comment: See the blue pencil button on the bottom right? Tap on that to enter the "edit mode" and the editing tools should appear.

Comment: OK, now I see. As soon as the document with the table is opened I can click anywhere in the document (inside or outside the table), to toggle the blue pencil icon in the lower-right-hand corner. When this happens a paste button with the ellipsis shows up. Clicking elsehwere and then in the table cell brings up a select all, cut, copy, paste, insert link, comment, and ellipsis. Clicking on the ellipsis for that cell pops up a menu with a white background on the bottom of the screen. The key to inserting a row is realizing that you can scroll such menu to find the insert row column above below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this within Google Drive/Docs app. Enter the edit mode of the document that you want to edit; tap on the cell you want to add row/column on, a hover menu will appear; then tap on the overflow menu (circled red):

[image]

A list of actions you can do on the cell will appear, scroll through the list of actions to find the ones for inserting row/columns:

[image]